# My syslog files have a file size of 71.7 GB

Tags: filesystem

When I run the command tail `tail /var/log/syslog.1`, this error pops up:

```
Sep 21 08:09:52 michael-pc io.elementary.cerbere.desktop[2091]: [00007ff48401b430] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
```

I had tried googling the problem but it seems like I am the only one who has this problem. I suspect this is the main reason why my log files' size is large.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585714/137608

Answer (score 0):

we have the same problem, this problem occurs when a locked system is running VLC (in my problem), here I include the log, to solve it i do truncate `sudo truncate -s 0 /var/lib/syslog`, this is [because of Nvidia Driver](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-435/+bug/1846374).

```
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i have got a solution to the problem. When I started VLC from the commandline (terminal), all the erros went there instead of filling up my disk.